# Match numbers in square brackets

Tags: regex, tcl

Please I try to match the following strings in a file:

```
test/test/abc_xyz[2][0]/abc
test/test/abc_xyz[2]/abc
test/test/abc_xyz/abc
```

I tried the following using regexp within a TCL script:

```
set match [regexp {^.*\/*\_xyz(|\[[0-9]{1,}\]|\[[0-9]{1,}\]\[[0-9]{1,}\])\/abc} $line extracted_string ]
```

Using this regular expression I managed to extract these lines:

```
"test/test/abc_xyz[2]/abc"
"test/test/abc_xyz/abc"
```

But Couldn't by any way extract lines similar to this:

```
test/test/abc_xyz[2][0]/abc
```

Could anybody tell me what may I be missing?

Comment: Your regex worked for me (in a java-based test), but: (1) you can use `+` instead of `{1,}` (2) I'd use an optional group rather than a bunch of ORs `^.*\/*\_xyz(\[[0-9]+\])*\/abc`

Comment: Can you put more code to illustrate how you are reading the file and where the result you are getting is going? The regex by itself is working fine albeit some improvements could be done on it to make it more efficient.

Comment: It would be helpful to have examples of the kind of lines you want to *avoid* matching, too. It's fairly pointless to suggest regular expressions if one doesn't know what not to match.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you've got this sequence — `[`, digit(s), `]` — that you want to match zero or more times. That leads to this: `(?:\[\d+\])*` as a general RE. Using that in place of your more complicated piece, we can get:

```
set match [regexp {^.*\/*\_xyz((?:\[\d+\])*)\/abc} $line extracted_string substring ]
```

That's shorter, and *much* easier to understand. I've also added `substring` in there to get the bracketed sequence. Dealing with that might be best done with a judicious `string map` of the brackets to spaces:

```
set numbers [string map {"[" " "  "]" " "} $substring]
```

Now you can use list operations (`llength`, `lindex`, `foreach`, etc.) on it…

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:** update  `^.*\/*\_xyz(\[\d+\])?\/abc`

**explain:**

your problem has here `(|\[[0-9]{1,}\]|\[[0-9]{1,}\]\[[0-9]{1,}\])` block.
i think you want to `[05]` have one time after `xyz` & before `/abc`

`(\[\d+\])`  for select `[05]`

`?`  for one or more time have

it may helpful. **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA8nQ5/2)**

Comment: your answer would be better if you explained what you did. Otherwise the reader has to go character-by-character looking for differences. Also, your link goes to a PCRE tester, but tcl doesn't use PCRE.